# Remove fixed grid row alignment

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, grid-layout

I am using [ionic-3](/questions/tagged/ionic-3) to create a grid layout.

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-12 col-xl-4 *ngFor="let news of news">
      <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>
          <img [src]="news.image"/>
          <ion-card-title>
            {{news.title}}
          </ion-card-title>
          {{news.text}}
        </ion-card-content>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col text-right>
            <ion-note>
              {{news.publish_at}}
            </ion-note>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

This is resulting in a layout as showed here:[image: column tops aligned at new row]

Instead the result I would wish for is:
[image: column top aligned to previous items bottom]

Which could be described as the default bootstrap method.

What do I need to do to get the preferred layout?